# Accessing PHP function from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to access a PHP function from an ajax call but I am running into all sorts of issues since is my first time doing something like this. I need help creating the function or fixing the one I have.

This is my ajax call (I will only post a small part of it since the complete function is irrelevant to the question)

```
 $.ajax({
    type        : 'post', 
    url         : 'data.php?action=checkname',
    data        : {'location':locationName},
    error       : function(data,status,error){
                console.log(data+': '+status+': '+error);
            },
    success     : function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }                   
    });
```

**PHP function**

```
<?php
    function checkname(){   <--- What do I pass in the function???

        $locations = $_POST['location'];

        echo $locations;

    }
?>
```

If I do this the "simple way" by just calling the file and do something like

```
$locations = $_POST['location'];

echo $locations;
```

I get the return that I need but it will be wrong to just have a small file for all the ajax calls that I need to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup for php doing something like this. Use a `Switch` and give each `action` a name in your `ajax` the name of the `Case` you want to activate. This way you can use the same file and call different functions as you see fit.

```
<?php
            $action = $_POST["action"];
            //check if it was sent using $_GET instead of $_POST 
            if(!$action)
            $action = $_GET["action"];

            switch($action){
                case 'checkname':
                 checkname();
                break;

                case 'otherfunction':
                 otherfunction();
                break;

             }//switch


     function checkname(){   

                $locations = $_POST['location'];

                echo $locations;

     }

     function otherfunction(){  

                //do something else

                //echo something;

     }
?>
```

I didn't put the ajax because you already had the ajax call. This part of your ajax is the name you will use for the action.  `data.php?action=checkname`
or you can use the data like this.

```
var action = 'checkname';

$.ajax({
    type        : 'post', 
    url         : 'data.php',
    data        : {'location':locationName,'action':action},
    error       : function(data,status,error){
                console.log(data+': '+status+': '+error);
            },
    success     : function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }                   
    });
```

You can use other ajax functions and just change variable action to the function you want to call.

Comment: I still don't see how you are sending in the information to the function besides checking what function you need to run...or you don't need to send in anything?

Answer (score 1):

Add some conditions to file:

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null;

switch($action) {
   case 'checkname':
       checkname();
   break;
   case default:
    // default action
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can code the php content like this:

```
  <?php
/*this part of code will be executed only when location parameter is set by post,
thus can send multiple ajax requests to a single file*/
  if(isset($_POST['location'] && $_POST['location'] != "")  
  {
     $location = $_POST['location'];
     echo checkname($location);
  }

function checkname($location) 
{
  return $location;
}
```

Comment: I thought of this method too but did not seem ideal for some reason due to the extra lines of code that I have to write to accommodate all options

Comment: there will be only one if condition for the complete ajax request just like a checksum and then all the code for that ajax will be inside it as normal, or kindly clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[`$functionName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) or [`call_user_func($functionName)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
$action = (isset($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : null;

if ( !empty($action) && function_exists($action) )
    call_user_func($action);
```